# How are Futures executed in an Akka actor

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, future

I'm trying to make a background task that performs a network call and stores the response in a database.  According to [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScheduledTasks), background tasks are supposed to use the scheduler within the Akka actor system.  I need to run a Future inside of this actor:

```
    actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay = new FiniteDuration(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        val future = network.request()
        future.flatMap(saveToDatabase(_))
    }
```

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Is this future guaranteed to get executed (to completion)?
2. Is it possible for other requests to follow up on the status of this task (whether it has finished or not)?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Presumably you found a problem of some sort, so update the question with the actual problem you found and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: @Tim I haven't had a problem, I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the Akka system.  Regardless, even if I did try it (and it ran), that isn't a guarantee that the Future will finish, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Future` in the `future` value is returned by the `network` object, so this object is responsible for executing the code that triggers the `Future`, not Akka. So you need to look at the documentation for the `request` call to see what completion guarantees there are for this `Future`.

The `Future` returned by the `flatMap` call uses the default execution context that is in scope when this task is created. But the `saveToDatabase` call is not guaranteed to be called because the `Future` can fail and `flatMap` is only called on success.

If you want to track the status of this task, send messages to a monitoring actor at various points in the execution. Other actors can then ask this monitoring actor about the progress of the task.